# How do I use a parameter value, set by a user in a web application, in an Optic API query in Marklogic?

Tags: php, marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf, marklogic-optic-api

> Blockquote

I have a web application (written in js) where a user can enter a name (along with other criteria) and a search against a ML database is performed and a tabular representation of some of the data associated to that name (or other search criteria) is returned.  In the first stages of development I wrote optic api queries with the value for name hard coded in the where statement of the  query. I did this so I could test that that the REST api was calling the query properly, etc.  That all is working and I can see the right results for that hard coded name being returned in the web app.  Now I want to pass the user supplied value for name to the Optic api query (EntityInformation_Optic_API_Query.json) to replace the hard coded value in where statement. How do I do this?  Thanks in advance.

---

owner edit

The application is written in PHP and I have copied code below. In this you can see where the optic api query is called and where the parameters are built.

````
<?php
if (!defined('RSS_BASE_URL')) exit;

use MarkLogic\MLPHP as MLPHP;

function rss_api_call($json, $params = array(), $resource = 'rows', $verb = 'POST')
{
    $json = __DIR__ . '/json/' . $json;

    if (!file_exists($json)) return false;

    $request = new MLPHP\RESTRequest('POST', 'rows', $params, file_get_contents($json), array('Content-type' => 'application/json'));
    $response = rss_get_client()->send($request);

    return json_decode($response->getBody());
}

function rss_api_entities()
{
    $params = array();

    return rss_api_call('EntityInformation_Optic_API_Query.json', $params);
    //return (empty($params)) ? '' : rss_api_call('EntityInformation_Optic_API_Query.json', $params);
}

function rss_api_search()
{
    $params = array();

    if (isset($_POST['companyname']) && !empty($_POST['companyname']))
    {
        $params['CompanyName'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['companyname']);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['EIN']) && !empty($_POST['ein']))
    {
        $params['EIN'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['ein']);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['city']))
    {
        $params['EntityCity'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['city']);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['state']) && !empty($_POST['state']))
    {
        $params['EntityState'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['state']);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['zip']) && !empty($_POST['zip']))
    {
        $params['EntityZip'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['zip']);
    }

    return rss_api_call('SearchResults_Optic_API_Query.json', $params);
    //return (empty($params)) ? '' : rss_api_call('SearchResults_Optic_API_Query.json', $params);
}

function rss_asset_path($path, $file_name)
{
    global $rss_manifest;

    if (empty($rss_manifest))
    {
        ob_start();

        include(__DIR__ . '/../manifest.json');

        $rss_manifest = json_decode(ob_get_clean(), true);
    }

    if (isset($rss_manifest[$file_name]))
    {
        $file_name = $rss_manifest[$file_name];
    }

    return RSS_ASSET_PATH . $path . '/' . $file_name;
}

function rss_box($title, $content)
{
    echo '<div class="rss-box">' .
        '<div class="rss-box-title">' . $title . '</div>' .
        '<div class="rss-box-content">' . $content . '</div>' .
        '</div>';
}

function rss_get_client()
{
    $mlphp = new MLPHP\MLPHP(array
    (
        'host' => RSS_API_HOST,
        'port' => RSS_API_PORT,
        'version' => RSS_API_VERSION,
        'username' => RSS_API_USERNAME,
        'password' => RSS_API_PASSWORD
    ));

    return $mlphp->getClient();
}

function rss_hidden_search_fields()
{
    echo '<div class="rss-hidden">';

    $fields = array('debug', 'companyname', 'ein', 'city', 'state', 'zip');

    foreach ($fields as $field)
    {
        echo (isset($_POST[$field])) ? '<input name="' . $field . '" type="hidden" value="' . htmlspecialchars($_POST[$field]) . '" />' : '';
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['social']))
    {
        $social = (is_array($_POST['social'])) ? $_POST['social'] : array($_POST['social']);

        foreach ($social as $social_network)
        {
            echo '<input name="social[]" type="hidden" value="' . htmlspecialchars($social_network) . '" />';
        }
    }

    echo (empty($_POST['social-select-all'])) ? '' : '<input name="social-select-all" type="hidden" value="1" />';
    echo '</div>';
}



Part of the EntityInformation_Optic_API_Query.json is below
-----

edit (information from a comment below):

The request will be a POST to /v1/rows. Does the following payload look correct? 

```javascript
{
    "$optic": {
        "ns": "op",
        "fn": "operators",
        "args": [
            {
                "ns": "op",
                "fn": "from-view",
                "args": [ "TestSchema", "SUT", null, null ]
            },
            {
                "ns": "op",
                "fn": "where",
                "args": [
                    {
                        "ns": "op",
                        "fn": "eq",
                        "args": [
                            {
                                "ns": "op",
                                "fn": "col",
                                "args": [ "CompanyName" ]
                            },
                            "${req.params.CompanyName}"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
````

Comment: Please post an example of your current code.

Comment: Rather than sending CompanyName along with the query, and expect it to get inserted server-side, why not just insert it client-side, e.g. before you send it away from PHP?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use "bind" parameters. So your plan would look like this:

```
{
  "$optic": {
    "ns": "op",
    "fn": "operators",
    "args": [
      {
        "ns": "op",
        "fn": "from-view",
        "args": [
          "TestSchema",
          "SUT",
          null,
          null
        ]
      },
      {
        "ns": "op",
        "fn": "where",
        "args": [
          {
            "ns": "op",
            "fn": "eq",
            "args": [
              {
                "ns": "op",
                "fn": "col",
                "args": [
                  "CompanyName"
                ]
              },
              {
                "ns": "op",
                "fn": "param",
                "args": [
                  "companyName"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And then when you post that to /v1/rows, you need to set the `companyName` bind parameter and type. So, add the follow parameters to your POST:

```
bind:companyName=${req.params.CompanyName}
bind:companyName:type=xs:string
```

Assuming `${req.params.CompanyName}` contains the company name value passed by the user.

As a side note, dealing with serialized Optic plans by hand can tough. I would recommend you put this behind a REST extension and just pass in the parameters. If you really want to keep the Optic plans in your middle tier, you can always use MarkLogic's Query Console to generate the plan with the proper `op.param()` calls where you want to have parameterized values. I.E. something like:

```js
const op = require('/MarkLogic/optic');
const plan = op
  .fromView("TestSchema", "SUT")
  .where(
    op.eq(
      op.col("CompanyName"), op.param("companyName")
    )
  )

plan.export()
```

Comment: Hi James.  I want to understand better what you mean by your comments "dealing with serialized Optic plans by hand" and putting "this behind a REST extension".  So, just to be clear I wrote the Optic API query in javascript through QConsole and then serialized it to JSON.  I then thought what was happening in PHP is that a REST API called that serialized query.  Is that what is supposed to happen, but may not be happening in our case?

Comment: The binding worked!  Now I just need to better understand what that is doing. Thanks for you help, it is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you @MeghanNoonan. Regarding your follow up question, you are using the serialized plans correct and as long as you stick to generating them in QConsole and using bind params for variables, you should be good. The "by hand" comment was referring to the fact that you were editing the plan and adding your "${req.params.CompanyName}" directly into it. I.E. editing the serialized plan by hand.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're setting up your application.

**REST API**

If your code is going to be a REST API extension, the function you write will have a `params` parameter. For JavaScript, this will be an object. See [The JavaScript Resource Extension Interface](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_15531). From that part of the docs:

> If the request is PUT `/v1/resource/my-ext?rs:p=1&rs:p=2`, then the value of `params.p` is ["1", "2"].

**Main Module**

If the client will access your code through a regular (non-REST) main module, then use the [`xdmp.getRequestField`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.getRequestField).

---

Edit: I updated your question with some more information from you comment. It looks to me like you've got a middle tier that is taking parameters from the client (browser) and using them to build a query to pass to `/v1/rows`. It looks like `"${req.params.CompanyName}"` is intended to be interpolated so that your middle tier gets the value of `req.params.CompanyName`, which would then be put into the string that gets sent to MarkLogic.

Is it possible that the `"${req.params.CompanyName}"` got added to a string with the quotes intact, so that the middle tier can't do the interpolation? If you can provide more information about how the payload to `/v1/rows` is being built, we might be able to offer more help.

Comment: It does use the REST API.  Does this look at all correct?{
"$optic": {
"ns": "op", 
"fn": "operators", 
"args": [
{
"ns": "op", 
"fn": "from-view", 
"args": [
"TestSchema", 
"SUT", 
null, 
null
]
}, 
{
"ns": "op", 
"fn": "where", 
"args": [
{
"ns": "op", 
"fn": "eq", 
"args": [
{
"ns": "op", 
"fn": "col", 
"args": [
"CompanyName"
]
}, 
"${req.params.CompanyName}"
]
}
]
},

Comment: Hello Dave, thanks for the guidance.  I am new to all this, as I am sure is evident.  I have updated my original question and added some PHP code where the optic api query is getting called from.

Answer (score 0):

For a Java or Node.js web application, the best approach might be to write a function that takes the value and builds and returns an Optic query.

In other environments, using a JSON representation and inserting the value would be safest.

Assembling the JSON serialization of the Optic query as a string is possible with escaping though sometimes hard to debug. On the MarkLogic enode, the JSON is parsed as JSON instead of evaluated, so there isn't a risk of injection attacks, but parse failures are possible.

Hoping that helps,